# angularjs URLs not resolving correctly on client that is running on second machine on local network

Tags: angularjs

Developed client on one machine, now trying to get it to run on another in the local network (I access the client using a URL containing an IP address rather than a hostname). The client on the new machine does not seem to recognize that it needs to use the IP to formulate URLs.

Comment: Inside your angular code, are you ever references your hostname?  Aka `localhost:8000/...` or anything of that nature?  Angular should be agnostic of the host and use absolute / relative urls.

Comment: I had references to localhost, and I changed them to the IP address, as in http://192.168.1.37. The problem is the urls represented in app.js, which start with /js/...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by upgrading to angularjs 1.7.7.